# Parsing data from a div tag using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML like this:

```
<div data-suppattrtype="test1" class="testclass">
  <p>
    Hello Test1
  </p>
</div>
<div data-suppattrtype="test2" class="testclass">
  <p></p>
    <div class="LotMoreContents">
      <p>
        First Time
      </p>
      <div id="Time">
        <input type="text" id="start-time" value="123"/>
        <input type="text" id="end-time" value="456"/>
      </div>
      <p>
        Second Time
      </p>
      <div id="Time">
        <input type="text" id="start-time" value="789"/>
        <input type="text" id="end-time" value="012"/>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I am trying to extract the various start & end times which are present in the div test2. What I am trying to do is to get all the times and store it in a JSON object similiar to this:

```
[{"startTime": "123", "endTime": "456"}, {"startTime":"789", "endTime": "012"}]
```

To do this, I am able to get the innerHTML of test2 via this:

```
$( document ).ready(function () {
  var $allDivs = $(this).find(".testclass");
  $allDivs.each(function() {
    var $suppAttrType = $(this).data('suppattrtype');
    if($suppAttrType === "test2") {
        /*Parse the the time objects within test2*/
    }
  });
});
```

I can access the HTML via `$(this)[0]` but I am unable to proceed further.

Comment: Are you trying to get the values of the `input` elements? If you change their ids to be unique you can just use `$('input#first-start-time').val()` to get the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First**

You should only assign `id` for elements that are unique to the page. Otherwise, use `class` (as what I modified on the below snippet)

`id="Time"` to `class="Time"`, `id="start-time"` to `class="start-time"` and `id="end-time"` to `class="end-time"`

**Second**

You need `JSON.stringify()` function to converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string.

```
$( document ).ready(function () {
  var $serializedTimes = [];

  var $allDivs = $(this).find(".testclass");
  $allDivs.each(function() {
    var $suppAttrType = $(this).data('suppattrtype');
    if($suppAttrType === "test2") {
      $(this).find(".Time").each(function(){
        var startTime = $(this).find(".start-time").val();
        var endTime   = $(this).find(".end-time").val();

        $serializedTimes.push({startTime: startTime, endTime: endTime});
      });
    }
  });

  console.log(JSON.stringify($serializedTimes));
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var serializedTimes = [];
    
  $(".testclass[data-suppattrtype='test2']").each(function(){
    $(this).find(".Time").each(function(){
      var startTime = $(this).find(".start-time").val();
      var endTime   = $(this).find(".end-time").val();
      
      serializedTimes.push({startTime: startTime, endTime: endTime});
    });
  });  
  
  console.log(JSON.stringify(serializedTimes));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-suppattrtype="test1" class="testclass">
  <p>
    Hello Test1
  </p>
</div>
<div data-suppattrtype="test2" class="testclass">
  <p></p>
    <div class="LotMoreContents">
      <p>
        First Time
      </p>
      <div class="Time">
        <input type="text" class="start-time" value="123"/>
        <input type="text" class="end-time" value="456"/>
      </div>
      <p>
        Second Time
      </p>
      <div class="Time">
        <input type="text" class="start-time" value="789"/>
        <input type="text" class="end-time" value="012"/>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to do it only when the attribute is test2?

Comment: I meant is it possible using var myContent = $(this).data('suppattrtype'); the myContent variable? Because I want to target only this part of the div, and there might exist similar tags in other blocks of the code as well.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't get it.

Comment: in myContent I have the HTML object right? Is it possible to just search for the time attribute within that?  $(".testclass[data-suppattrtype='test2']") will search in the entire html file right? I would prefer doing the search for time within the content I have already retrieved

Comment: Yes. It will search for all elements with class name `testclass` and `data-suppattrtype` `test2`. But `$(this).find(".Time").each(` will search within the element `testclass` and `data-suppattrtype` `test2` only. Your `var $allDivs = $(this).find(".testclass");` will retrieve the entire HTML file too.

Comment: Yes I know. This is just for mockup i did as in my original code, I have narrowed it down to the section I want and then do the processing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155564/discussion-between-user1692342-and-duc-filan).